# How to use Android App Bundles-Dynamic Features with visual studio 2017

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

In Google Play Console I came across

> App size savings using the Android App Bundle-
>
> Your app could be 38.4% smaller if you used the Android App Bundle.
>   The APKs generated from the app bundle give your users smaller, more
>   optimized downloads. [Learn how](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9006925)
>
> This calculation is based on your latest production release and the
>   XXHDPI ARMv7 device configuration.

This is all about reducing the size of apk file & it claims to have many benifits like Keep apps smaller, Serve users the functionality and configurations they need, Reduce development complexity by removing the need to build and publish multi-APKs name a few.

Can we develop same thing for Xamarin with visual studio?

Comment: `.aab` files are not currently supported via Xamarin.Android, you can build your own using the Android SDK cmd line tools as there is no technical reason a Xamarin app can not support them like the technical limitations that prevent a Xamarin.Android from being deployed as an Play/Android Instant app. Now the dynamic features of App Bundles are a different story and we have had complete failure in the Play store beta of it in trying to use Xamarin AOT'd shared libraries vs IL-based assembles).

Comment: I do not know how your app/apk is layout out, be assumably you are including multiple Mono runtime ABIs in your apk and thus can use ABI split-APKs instead to achieve the same effect as they are supported via the Xamarin.Android build process. It is these split-apps that Google is trying to replace via the "Android App Bundle" format, and of course they are also adding dynamic modules features to `.abb` (which are not directly support via Xamarin.Android either)

Comment: @SushiHangover - Thank you for valuable information. Currently I am not using .apk per selected abi but using 3 architectures `armeabi, armeabi-v7, x86`, these leading apk to approximately 25MB than I thought of reducing file size.

Comment: Did you manage to use Android App Bundles with Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: What exactly is your end goal if I may ask? Are you trying to reduce your file size or generate `.aab's`?

Comment: @FreakyAli - I wanted to reduce APK file size. However, this question is more than year old. Now I am using Sdk and User assemblies and ProGuard to reduce APK file size.

Comment: Sorry my bad, Anyway do let me know in case if you still want an answer to it!

Comment: It's not about I want answer or not. If you know you can write it, so it would help others.

Comment: Visual Studio has now included the aab feature in ui also Check out the preview version here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/10/10.1#ide-support-for-android-app-bundle-publishing-format

Answer (score 1):

App bundle now avalaible in **Visual Studio 2019 v.16.2**

I generated Android App Bundle in xamarin using **Developer Command Prompt Visual Studio 2019 v.16.2**

```
msbuild -restore XamAndroidApp.csproj -t:SignAndroidPackage -p:Configuration=Release -p:AndroidKeyStore=True -p:AndroidSigningKeyStore=filename.keystore -p:AndroidSigningStorePass=password -p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias=keyAlias -p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=password
```

Follow this [link](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/9/9.4#initial-support-for-android-app-bundle-publishing-format) for more infos

Hope this help someone

Comment: You can run the `MSBuild` command by only installing the "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019" too.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Hakiza, above, the command line is the best bet currently to build an Android App Bundle (aab). The only item I would add is to include the command switch for actually generating the bundle. Add the following command switch to the msbuild command: `-p:AndroidPackageFormat=aab`.

So, the entire command line would be:

```
=> msbuild -restore XamAndroidApp.csproj -t:SignAndroidPackage -p:Configuration=Release -p:AndroidKeyStore=True -p:AndroidSigningKeyStore=filename.keystore -p:AndroidSigningStorePass=password -p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias=keyAlias -p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=password -p:AndroidPackageFormat=aab
```

Answer (score 0):

Please select only 64 bit architecture. `armeabi-v7a` `arm64-v8a` only.

Properties -> Android Options -> Advanced -> Supported Architecture.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set the Package format to AAB in your Android Manifest,
Set the Build Version for the APP your are going to publish.
Then Find the Keystore with your Hash from google and paste it in the same folder your Android Version of the App is.
Then open a command Prompt and type the following code.

```
msbuild -restore AppName.Android.csproj -t:SignAndroidPackage -p:Configuration=Release -p:AndroidKeyStore=True -p:AndroidSigningKeyStore=Keystore.keystore -p:AndroidSigningStorePass=password-p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias=Alias-p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=password
```

Follow this [tutorial](http://www.geojorgx.com/programacion/tutorial-xamarin-app-bundle-2019/) for more information.