# How many Supported architectures should I choose while creating apk file

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, apk, cpu-architecture

I have android app, size of my android apk file is 25MB. So while creating apk file I want to know how many `Supported Architectures` is must, in order to reduce apk  size.

Targeting 4.1 to 8.1 Android version.

[image]

Comment: Publish as App Bundle (https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle/) and apk downloaded to user's device will only include code for cpu etc  of that device

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly - In Visual Studio I can't use App Bundle check one of my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715205/how-to-use-android-app-bundles-dynamic-features-with-visual-studio-2017

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1709 ...even if App Bundles are not directly supported right now; there still is the `bundletool`, which is CLI based - and therefore could be setup as an external tool.

Comment: @MartinZeitler - Thank you for your input.

Comment: Generally , armeabi and armeabi-v7a is needed.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT - But [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155309/application-is-incompatible-with-tablets/36250171#36250171)  said `armeabi` is deprecated. In the answer of this question GHakim said `armeabi-v7a` and `arm64-v8a` required.

Comment: Yeah , GHakim is right ! it should  be updated.If `armeabi ` already be deprecated,then `armeabi-v7a` and `arm64-v8a` are required.They have been updating in this order(armeabi ->armeabi-v7a ->arm64-v8a ).If old version of them is not used in people,then need use new one.It seems that I have not been updated in time for this.About `x86`  and `x86_64` , they are used in pad.If your app not run in pad ,so not add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455603/which-xamarin-abis-should-we-support) it gives you a brief idea on what abi's should be used while using xamarin android.

I would also like to add that `x86` and `x86_64` are usually emulators and hence Its okay if you don't have them in release mode, the other two namely `armeabi-v7a` and `arm64-v8a` are the abi's that cover the most devices so it is best that you have both of these in your release mode the other two are not required for real devices but mandatory for most emulators

Goodluck revert in case of queries

Comment: In your given link, it is said _Make sure you are at least checking the following architectures: armeabi-v7a and x86_ and you mentioned that `x86` not needed.

Comment: The reason I said that is because there are almost no x86 real devices available, did you read this `"I would also like to add that x86 and x86_64 are usually emulators and hence Its okay if you don't have them in release mode"`?